# JavaFx fix Label to left site of vbox

Tags: java, javafx

I need to place a Label to the left side of a VBox, but the Vbox is placed inside a BorderPane with setRight(). Code looks like the following:

```
HUD hud;

public GUIGame() {  //extends BorderPane
    setMinSize(TILE_SIZE*8, TILE_SIZE*8);
    setPrefSize(TILE_SIZE*8, TILE_SIZE*8);
    pg = new PlayGround();
    setLeft(pg.createContent()); //createContent returns a parent
    hud = new HUD(pg);
    setRight(hud);
}
public HUD(PlayGround pg){ //extends VBox
        setSpacing(50);
        addLabels(pg);
}
private void addLabels(PlayGround pg){
        final double X_TRANSLATE_LABLE = HUD_WIDTH /2 - 35;
        Label myLabel = new Label();
        myLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.concat(fooString, ": ", longFooString));
        myLabel.setFont(new Font(MAX_FONT_SIZE));
        myLabel.setTranslateX(-X_TRANSLATE_LABLE);
        getChildren().addAll(myLabel,...,otherLabels)
}
```

I set the translateX to move the label to the left side of the HUD. But as longFooString gets longer (would still fit inside the HUD) the label moves inside my PlayGround (probably because it tried to keep the XTranslate distance). Any way to fix this? I tried using a GridPane but that didnt really work out. I also experimented with setting the maximum width of the label, didnt work either.

Comment: [mcve] please .. an aside: don't extend layout (except when enhancing their _generic layouting_), instead use and configure one or more of the existing implementations. Their functionality is well specified in their respective class doc - be sure to read that carefully :)

Comment: ---Fixed it--- JavaFx needs the width of the HUD I debugged with setBackgound and it marked only half if the HUD.. setXXXWidth() with your desired width and it will fix the problem! And thanks @kleopatra I'm using Vbox objects as attributes from now on!